# How to stop rejection of DNS queries?

Tags: firewall, linux-networking, firewalld

Although service `dns` is allowed through firewalld, DNS queries received through an `internal` interface are denied.

Here is the network:

```
PC ------------- SERVER ---------------- DNS Server
> nslookup       # firewall-cmd          DNS service
192.168.2.11 --- ens244 192.168.2.1
                 net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
                 ens160 192.168.1.1 ---- 192.168.1.11
```

This are the zone settings:

```
[christine@montreal ~]$ sudo firewall-cmd --list-all --zone=internal
internal (active)
  target: default
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces: ens224
  sources:
  services: cockpit dhcpv6-client dns mdns samba-client ssh
  ports:
  protocols:
  forward: no
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports:
  source-ports:
  icmp-blocks:
  rich rules:
[christine@montreal ~]$
```

This are the log messages:

```
Jun 10 <...> montreal.<...>: FINAL_REJECT: IN=ens224 OUT=ens160 MAC=<...>  SRC=192.168.2.11 DST=192.168.1.11 LEN=71 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=127 ID=61889 PROTO=UDP SPT=53254 DPT=53 LEN=51
```

*Tried*: Rejection stops when `target` is set to `ACCEPT`, but this is not the strategy I want.

Comment: Not familiar with firewalld but you are forwarding DNS querys on IP level (instead of application level with a DNS forwarder like dnsmasq). So you need to get firewalld to make iptables (its backend) to allow corresponding forward traffics (instead of input traffics), or forward on application level.

Comment: @TomYan The `net.ipv4.ip_forward` parameter has the SERVER routing towards the two subnets. This works well for any IP traffic when no firewall filtering interferes.
Do you mean that forwarded traffic is treated differently (by firewalld/nftables) than inbound traffic?

Comment: Yes, iptables/nftables use different chains / hooks for input and forward traffics respectively. Your firewalld configuration may be allowing dns / ssh / etc. traffics that are destined for this server (on Layer 3 / IP Layer) itself, but that does NOT necessarily mean that you are instructing the firewall to also allow such traffics to be forwarded (i.e. when such traffics are destined for this server on Layer 2 / MAC layer only).

Comment: Thank you @TomYan, you make me progress. The next step for me is to learn how to inspect and configure `nftables` chains. **Any help appreciated**. (I didn't expect this SERVER machine to be that hard to set up.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*DISCLAIMER: I am not really experienced / familiar with firewalld, so my judgement / opinion might be biased / inaccurate.*

It's actually not very difficult to allow IP forwarding between two interfaces / network, especially if you want to "statelessly" allow that bidirectionally (i.e. allowing hosts on *both* sides to initiate communication with a host on another side). You really just need to create a zone, add the two interfaces to the zone, and then `--add-forward` the zone. (There's also `--add-masquerade` btw, which you *might* need/want as well.)

The problem is firewalld seems super inflexible and dumb to me. As I just mentioned, there doesn't seem to be any way at all for you to just "statelessly" allow forwarding of just one direction (while the other direction is only allowed "statefully", like typical LAN-WAN case). But perhaps that isn't a corcern in your case (since both network seems more or less an internal one, judging with the IP subnet blocks that are used).

An even bigger problem is, its design doesn't allow you to further cherry-pick an interface that has been added to a zone (for forwarding) to allow inbound traffics destined for this host. You can only allow with IP (ranges) by using "rich rules".

You can't even use another *source zone* (which has higher precedence than *interface zone*) to do that. For example, if you have a source zone for `192.168.2.0/24` that allows ssh connection or so to this host, it will overrides forwarding rules that are added by the interface zone just configured. Even if you `--add-forward` this zone as well, it will only allow something like "source 192.168.2.0/24 (logical AND) destination 192.168.2.0/24". If you additionally add `0.0.0.0/0` as a source to this zone, than you will be allowing *ALL* (from `0.0.0.0/0` to `0.0.0.0/0`) forwarding traffics.

As I said at the beginning, these might all be just misjudgement. It could be just me not knowing how to use it right. Regardless I'd rather write my own nftables ruleset anyway. I hardly see any point in using it.

In any case, here's an example zone (file) that you *might* want to take as a reference:

```
$ cat /etc/firewalld/zones/myForward.xml 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<zone>
  <rule family="ipv4">
    <source address="192.168.1.0/24"/>
    <service name="ssh"/>
    <accept/>
  </rule>
  <rule family="ipv4">
    <source address="192.168.150.0/24"/>
    <service name="dns"/>
    <accept/>
  </rule>
  <interface name="wlan0"/>
  <interface name="bridge0"/>
  <forward/>
</zone>
```

It allows forwarding between wlan0 and bridge0 statelessly-bidirectionally, and allows ssh connection *to this host* from `192.168.1.0/24` (IP subnet on the `wlan0` side), and allow DNS requests *to this host* from `192.168.150.0/24` (IP subnet on the `bridge0` side).

(This is the only zone file in /etc/firewalld/zones/. I'm not using any builtin zones.)

EDIT: I've sort of found out a way to statelessly allow forward for only one direction. You can add the "WAN" interface (e.g. ens160) to the builtin `public` zone. For "LAN" interfaces that you want to forward traffic from (e.g. ens244), you do NOT need to add it to the public zone. However, you CANNOT add it to ANY other zone either, since that other zone will have its own forward configuration (it does NOT matter whether you `--add-forward` that zone). (You can check with `nft list chain inet firewalld filter_FORWARD_ZONES`. Note the `goto`s.)